# Creating a Table in PDF and updating the values in the table SharePoint 2010 programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, pdf

I am looking into adding a table into pdf with the columns - approver name and approver comments using c# code in console application. and then update the columns with values like "approver1"  "approved" etc.(This code will later reside in a timer job). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to generate PDF files from information in SharePoint.  If that is correct, you can use iTextSharp to process the PDF file (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).  If your PDF document has a pre-defined layout and you are just adding information to the PDF document, you should simply create a PDF form and then use iTextSharp to fill out the form with the SharePoint data.  I have an example of something similar over on my blog: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-fill-out-and-flatten-pdf-forms-with-itextsharp/